# Is it possible to have mobile friendly version for this site?

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to have a mobile friendly version for this site.

I tried the site in an Android based smartphone and the menu completely get overlapped.

Comment: It works fine from my iPhone...

Comment: Fine on my Android powered Galaxy S2. Which phone are you using?

Comment: I am using Motorola Defy+

Comment: You're hard-core, Pankaj--I need a browser, Google, the docs, or/or a VM to ask/answer TRex questions! Unless you're connected all of that from your phone? :-)

Comment: Ofcourse, all of them and even much are there in Motorola Defy+
And no I am not at all hard-core, only looks for very much feature range in the budget and this provides everything that even iPhone does not provide :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using an Android App like http://rectangularsoftware.com/stackanywhere/

Comment: looks promising; will give it a try :)